# Will this method make me lose weight and reach my maintenance goal weight?

Tags: weight-loss, diet, obesity

I am guessing that I eat(or ate) too much (before) and that is why I am obese.

What I eat include a Asian diet with occasional eating out. It also included regular snacking until about a year ago but now I only irregularly eat snacks.

I have thought of a method to lose my weight without having withdrawal symptoms of starving without food.

I thought of listing my normal recurring diet food items by calories in them and then removing up to four items entirely. Such that it puts me slightly below the amount of calories for my Basal metabolic rate.

Would this method work or do you think that it needs improvement/personalisation/scraping?

Thank you for your answers in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure what constitutes a "Asian" diet, can you expand? If you are calorie counting then I suggest IfItMeetsYourMacros (iimym.com) for giving you a idea about how many calories to eat in a day. As you rightly point out, portion control (weighing your food) is important to gauge calorie intake but cutting out food entirely can be not beneficial.

Comment: Brother I don't count calories.what i did to lose fat was cutting out unhealthy foods from my diet and the starvation of that goes away after 3 days or more and i did 20 min cardio daily like walking so you can also try this method.I also replaced my unhealthy foods with apples.

Comment: @ASD while your weight loss method is valid for you, it cannot be applied to everyone. You may not have counted calories but you certainly cut them; you do not know the calorie intake of S.Summer, it may be that cutting just unhealthy foods still leaves them at a calorie surplus and they will still gain weight.